# Several Questions related to Convergence and Cauchy Sequences

Tags: real-analysis

1) a sequence ($x_n$) of irrational numbers that converges to a rational limit

I pick $\pi$/n....I am wondering is $\pi$/n an irrational number since rational number is any number can be written in fraction form.

2) a sequence ($x_n$) of rational numbers that converges to an irrational limit

My guy feeling tells me this is possible...however I am not able to find an example...does anyone think of one?

3) a sequence ($x_n$) containing subsequences converging to every number in N

I know 1,1,1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5 works....I am wondering does N work? If not, why not?

4) a sequence $(x_n)$ that is not Cauchy, but for which $|x_{n+1} - x_n|$ converges to $0$

I am told a sequence of partial sums $x_{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{i}$ works. However, doesn't this partial sum converge to 1 since  $x_{n+1} = 1/2+1/3+1/4+1/5+...+1/(n+1)$ and $x_n = 1+1/2+1/3+1/4+1/5+...+1/n$? If we subtract $x_n$ from $x_{n+1}$, we get $1/(n+1) - 1$ which is $-n/(n+1)$. Then doesn't $|x_{n+1} - x_n|$ converge to 1?

Comment: Regarding 2: How about 3, 3.1, 3.14, 3.141, 3.1415, 3.14159, ...?
Regarding 4: You're missing the first term in your expansion of $x_{n+1}$.

Comment: Thanks. Can anyone answer my Q3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (1), you're wrong at "rational number is any number can be written in fraction form". That's not quite true; a rational number is one that can be written as a fraction *of integers*. If simply being the result of a division were enough, then every number would be rational, because any $x$ can be written as $\frac x1$, and then the concept of "rational number" wouldn't be worth much.

For (3), if by "does N work" you mean you're suggesting the sequence
$$1,2,3,4,5,6,\ldots $$
then that doesn't work. For example you can't find any subsequence that converges to $1$. Since the indices that make up a subsequence must, by definition, be strictly increasing, the $k$th term of any subsequence cannot come from an earlier term than the $k$th term of the original sequence. And that means that every term *except for the first* of any subsequence of the above sequence must be $\ge 2$, so there's no way the terms of the subsequence can be arbirtarily close to $1$ late in the subsequence.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding questions $1$ and $2$:

$\{s_n\}=\{2,2.7,2.71,2.718,\ldots\}$

The sequence is made up of rational numbers, but tends to $e\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$, as $n\to\infty$.

$\{s_n\}=\{\dfrac{\pi}{n^3}\}$

The sequence is made up of irrational numbers, but tends to $0\in\mathbb{Q}$, as $n\to\infty$.

Of course $\{\dfrac{\pi}{n}\}$ would be valid as well.

Comment: To make sure if we multiple, add, subtract, divide any irrational number by n, is the irrational number still irrational?

Comment: Not necessarily:

$\sqrt{2}+(1-\sqrt{2})=1\in\mathbb{Q}$.


$\sqrt{2}\cdot 0=0$.


For multiplication, if $a\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$, and $b$ is non-zero, then $ab\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @afsdfdfsaf: Yes, an irrational number divided by an integer is still irational. Consider: If this was not true then for some irrational $x$ it would be that $x/n=p/q$ for some integers, $n$, $p$, and $q$. But then, multiplying by $n$ on both sides we get $x=np/q$, so $x$ was rational after all, a contradiction. You can construct similar proofs for addition, subtraction and multiplication (by a nonzero number).

Comment: @SujaanKunalan: But $(1-\sqrt2)$ is not an $n$ (which usually implies an integer), so that's not a counterexample.

Comment: Thanks. Can anyone answer my Q3 ?

Comment: Ah, I forgot that $n\in\mathbb{N}$ when I made my comments, so of course Henning is correct. So to reiterate, if $n\in\mathbb{N}$, and $a\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$, then $an\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}, \frac{a}{n}\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$, and $a\pm n\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}.$